# Why does Javascript's Math.pow() seem to return a rounded value compared to the same in C?

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, v8

My understanding is that both C's `double` and Javascript's numbers are IEEE 754 64 bit floating point numbers. I am trying to port some code from C to Nodejs, and I am running into what appears to be a rounding error in Javascript's `Math.pow()`.

Here is my C program:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  double shared = 729;
  double exponent = 15;
  double prime = 1500450271;
  double power = pow(shared, exponent);
  double mod = fmod(power, prime);
  int intResult = (int) mod;
  printf("shared: %lf, exponent: %lf, prime: %lf, pow: %lf, mod: %lf, result: %i\n",
      shared, exponent, prime, power, mod, intResult); 
}
```

The output of which is:

```
shared: 729.000000, exponent: 15.000000, prime: 1500450271.000000, pow: 8727963568087711970669458465954849888403456.000000, mod: 1488486878.000000, result: 1488486878
```

Interestingly, when I try to perform this calculation in Javascript (tested in node, Chrome, Firefox)

I get the following result:

```
> Math.pow( 729, 15)
8.727963568087713e+42
> Math.pow( 729, 15 ) % 1500450271;
93655693
```

In addition, when I store the power result from C in a Javascript number:

```
> 8727963568087711970669458465954849888403456.0
8.727963568087712e+42
```

Note the difference -> `8.727963568087713e+42 !== 8.727963568087712e+42`, so understandably the modulo operation fails to produce the same result.

I've had a look at the source for v8's implementation of Math.pow, but the masm macros look like greek to me atm.

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: This is similar to the following in javascript: var x=0.1+0.1+0.1; console.log(x); It will print 0.30000000000000004

Comment: @TomasMatejicek No, that's just ordinary floating point limitations. Here two implementations are inaccurate *in different ways*.

Comment: @delnan - not totally getting how the C version is inaccurate, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @dwerner I never said that. Both are approximations. The important part is that those approximations are different. (But yes, the C code's result is incorrect, 729**15 =  8727963568087712425891397479476727340041449.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECMAScript ("JavaScript") doesn't make any guarantees about the precision of the `pow` function. [ECMA-262 says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.13):

> Returns an implementation-dependent approximation to the result of raising x to the power y.

Neither does the C language. Only the optional Annex F of the C99 spec refers to IEC 60559 (same as IEEE 754), but `pow` isn't one of the basic operations for which there are precision guarantees.

In your case, the result you get from Node.js is slighty more inaccurate than the result from your C program, but this doesn't violate the spec. You simply have to live with this kind of differences. Calling `fmod` on huge floating point numbers is foolish anyway.

**Edit:** The reason for the discrepancy is probably excess precision of the x87 80-bit "double extended" format. Take the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int base = atoi(argv[1]);
    int exp  = atoi(argv[2]);
    printf("pow: %.15e\n", pow(base, exp));
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with gcc and no special options:

```
$ gcc -Wall -O2 pow.c -lm -o pow
$ ./pow 729 15
pow: 8.727963568087712e+42
```

Compiled with `-mpc64`:

```
$ gcc -mpc64 -Wall -O2 pow.c -lm -o pow
$ ./pow 729 15
pow: 8.727963568087713e+42
```

Comment: - delnan triggered my understanding, but it's really great to have the supporting facts behind the problem. Thanks!